# How to Export Data from Excel workbook with multiple worksheets to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am quite new to Hadoop Development, have got a challenge to export data from an excel **workbook with Multiple sheets to HDFS?**  I have successfully exported the single sheet workbook, but I am stuck with multiple sheets! The data is in structured form.

What are the options I should choose? Please advise...

Many Thanks

Comment: can't you save as xml?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But this is a repeated process, so I would like to know if there is any PIG, HIVE or MAP Reduce functions or code for the same.

Comment: write a UDF and you are set

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process the Excel sheets using something like the python package xlrd.

Something like this:

```
import xlrd
import csv
import sys

def csv_from_excel(input_file,output_file,sheet_index):
  wb = xlrd.open_workbook(input_file)
  sh = wb.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
  your_csv_file = open(output_file, 'wb')
  wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file)
  for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
    row = []
    for s in sh.row_values(rownum):
      row.append(s)
    wr.writerow(row)
  your_csv_file.close()
```

You could probably define a UDF to do this processing for you buy I have no experience with that. I would personally use something like this as a pre-process step before you kick off your M/R job.